# Vagrant Host Unreachable - Possible Conflict

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have multiple Vagrant 1.7.4 boxes running on VirtualBox 5, but I believe I am running into conflicts with my network setup. I can always "vagrant ssh" to a box when it comes online, but it's hit or miss if I can access the webserver. Rebooting my machine or starting the boxes in a different order can correct the problem. I am running OSX El Capitan. Here is the relevant setup:

**Machine 1 (can't access webserver from OSX):**

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6B:1C:DD  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6b:1cdd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:572 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80340 (78.4 KiB)  TX bytes:70508 (68.8 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:3E:44:A3  
          inet addr:10.10.10.10  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3e:44a3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:1128 (1.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

**Machine 2 (working fine):**

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.11.11.11"

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6B:1C:DD  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6b:1cdd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7430638 (7.0 MiB)  TX bytes:482303 (470.9 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:73:39:23  
          inet addr:10.11.11.11  Bcast:10.11.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe73:3923/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5646 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:625645 (610.9 KiB)  TX bytes:6934485 (6.6 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1144652 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1144652 (1.0 MiB)
```